# How do I include unit test and exclude integration test during Build and Unit test phase and vice versa after the deployment for Gradle project?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, integration-testing, jenkins-groovy

we are using Gradle. We are using Jenkins for our CI-CD. The Jenkins stages in our project is `Checkout`, `Build and unit test`, `Sonar`, `Docker`, `Approve deployment`, `Dev deployment` and `Integration test`.
How can I run only unit tests during `Build and unit test` step in Jenkins and run only `Integration test` after Dev Deployment Jenkins?

I have attached a screenshot wherein I have included Integration test and excluded Unit tests in `build.gradle` file, but it's not the correct way.

Below is my Jenkins Groovy file:

```
Map buildOptions(Map optionParams) {
    return [
            javaVersion: '11.0'
    ] + optionParams
}

void call(Map optionParams = [:]) {
    buildIfNotRelease(buildOptions(optionParams))
}

boolean buildIfNotRelease(Map options = [:]) {

    def buildCommand = options.buildSystem == 'maven' ? 'mvn clean package' : './gradlew clean build'

    return sh(script: "export JAVA_VERSION=${options.javaVersion};. /etc/profile.d/jenkins.sh;${buildCommand}"
//            returnStatus: true
    ) == 0
}
```

[image: build.gradle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your integration test into different `sourceSet` using the [jvm-test-suite-plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html).

This way you have a dedicated tasks for `test` and `integrationTest` and you don't have to deal with `include`/`exclude` stuff.

If you want to have some common test code, then use the [java-test-fixtures-plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures).